# SQL query takes longer time when date range is smaller?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a simple select statement which selects data from a SQL Server 2000 (so old) table with about 10-20 million rows like this -

```
@startDate = '2014-01-25' -- yyyy-mm-dd
@endDate = '2014-02-20'

SELECT 
    Id, 6-7 other columns
FROM 
    Table1 as t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Table2 as t2 ON t1.Code = t2.Code
WHERE 
    t1.Id = 'G59' -- yes, its a varchar
    AND (t1.Entry_Date >= @startDate AND t1.Entry_Date < @endDate)
```

This gives me about 40 K rows in about 10 seconds. But, if I set @startDate = '2014-01-30', keeping @endDate same ALWAYS, then the query takes about 2 min 30 sec

To produce the same number of rows, I tried it with 01-30 again and it took 2 min 48 seconds.

I am surprised to see the difference. I was not expecting the difference to be so big. Rather, I was expecting it to take the same time or lesser for a smaller date range.

What could be the reason for this and how do I fix it ?

Comment: Have you recently inserted and/or deleted a large number of rows? It could be that the statistics on the table's indices are out of date, and thus the query optimizer will go for a "index seek + key lookup" scenario on the smaller date range - but that turns out to be slower than just doing a table/clustered index scan. I would update the statistics and try again - any improvement?

Comment: @marc_s - I don't know if any rows have been inserted recetly. It is likely though. I don't insert any. I only do the extraction (ETL). I am still learning so, I did not understand your comment. How do I update the statistics ? I am not DBA btw. Thanks.

Comment: [TechNet article on how to update statistics in SQL Server 2000](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260645%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: @marc_s - I tried doing UPDATE STATISTICS on both tables and got the error - User does not have permission to perform this operation on table. So, its time for DBA help. Any alternatives ?

Comment: @marc_s - Can you please explain this in more detail - "the statistics on the table's indices are out of date, and thus the query optimizer will go for a "index seek + key lookup" scenario on the smaller date range - but that turns out to be slower than just doing a table/clustered index scan" Thanks

Comment: The query optimizer uses statistics to determine whether it's faster to just do a table scan (just read all the table's data pages and select the rows that match), or whether it's faster to **search** for the search value in an index; that index typically doesn't contain all the data - so once a match is found, a **key lookup** needs to be performed on the table to get at the data - which is an expensive operation, so it's only viable for small sets of data. If out-of-date statistics "mislead" the query optimizer, it might choose a suboptimal execution plan.

Comment: @marc_s - can you write your comments as an answer ? i'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you recently inserted and/or deleted a large number of rows? It could be that the statistics on the table's indices are out of date, and thus the query optimizer will go for a "index seek + key lookup" scenario on the smaller date range - but that turns out to be slower than just doing a table/clustered index scan.

I would recommend to update the statistics (see this [TechNEt article on how to update the statistics](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260645%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)) and try again - any improvement?

The query optimizer uses statistics to determine whether it's faster to just do a table scan (just read all the table's data pages and select the rows that match), or whether it's faster to search for the search value in an index; that index typically doesn't contain all the data - so once a match is found, a key lookup needs to be performed on the table to get at the data - which is an expensive operation, so it's only viable for small sets of data. If out-of-date statistics "mislead" the query optimizer, it might choose a suboptimal execution plan

Comment: I have a similar query which gets results for "this week" and its very slow. when i checked the statistics using "dbcc show_statistics" it was updated a week before. "last week" runs fast. 
Adding to this, does this means we need to update statistics every week so that "this week" report runs fast.
"this week" runs slow and has serial stream execution plan.
"last week" runs fast and has parallel streams execution plan.

Can you help?

Comment: Old question, old answer, but still relevant to SQL Server today (~2017) as a best practice to help ensure your queries are performing at the highest level of efficiency. I just had this same issue with a table that receives data every day (contains greater than 300mil rows). After updating the stats for this database, both queries use the same index (the faster one) and the query that used to never finish now finishes in <2 seconds.